# Devo mostrar mensagens de erro genéricas como, senha ou usuário errado, ou mensagens específicas?

Tags: segurança, ux

É comum em muitos sistemas ao inserir o usuário e a senha incorreta, o sistema nos informar que um deles está errado, mas não exatamente qual (isso acontece também aqui no Stack Overflow).

Isto acontece para proteger os dados? Ou poderíamos dizer que é porque é mais fácil fazer dessa forma?

Hoje em sistemas como o Google e a Microsoft é diferente do passado, agora primeiro pedem o *login* e só se estiver correto pedem a senha.

Comment: Curtamente falando: isso é para evitar dar dicas a um possível atacante que ele acertou o usuário; longamente falando: não fazer a verificação de usuário e senha separador implica em um acesso único ao banco, o que implica em ganho de performance por não esperar latência de comunicação. Sem falar que consultar só um ou os dois tem basicamente o mesmo peso. Esperando alguém fornecer uma resposta mais completa e fundamentada do assunto

Comment: Pois bem, eu não sei dizer porque o Google mudou o design de validação de senha, mas esses eram os porquês que eu sabia

Comment: Isso basicamente depende do volume de usuários da aplicação. Se você tem um pequeno sistema, com uma centena de usuários, a informação de usuário correto é preciosa. No caso do google e da MS, a grande maioria das coisa que você "chuta" é um usuário válido, então fica irrelevante proteger esta parte das credenciais, o que por consequência permite repensar no mecanismo. Sobre a usabilidade da UI, são soluções equivalentes. O "esforço" pra trocar de campo na mesma tela equivale ao de entrar o nome de usuário para pular para a tela seguinte, então a escolha dos passos se dará por outros critérios

Comment: Curiosidade: como sempre, a Google implenta as coisas "mais ou menos". Já reparei em vários lugares que tem hora que você acerta o usuário, mas o avatar não aparece (o que estraga totalmente a vantagem de você avaliar se está no formulário correto, e não num fake). No começo achei que realmente poderia ser um ataque MitM, mas confirmei em lugares e equipamentos completamente diferentes e com mais de uma conta (de pessoas diferentes, inclusive).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Acredito que as respostas são boas, mas a resposta do @Stormwind sobre "uma mensagem de erro genérica" me deixou um pouco intrigado.*

> Hoje em sistemas como o Google e a Microsoft é diferente do passado, agora primeiro pedem o login e só se estiver correto pedem a senha.

Acredito que isto ocorra porque a senha não é tão relevante. Já existe autenticação em dois (ou mais) fatores. No passado, apenas o conhecimento da senha já dava acesso a conta. Hoje em dia isso não se aplica, agora você precisa de mais do que apenas a senha.

Especificamente o Google permite até o uso de FIDO U2F, que exige uma chave física, USB, que nela contêm uma chave ECDSA, no qual assina o "desafio".

Enfim, mesmo que o atacante saiba o e-mail e a senha ainda terá um trabalho. Por isso, acredito que se tornou irrelevante o atacante saber apenas o e-mail e como já foi dito, passaram a informar o usuário o que está errado, melhorando sua experiencia.

> Isto acontece para proteger os dados? Ou poderíamos dizer que é porque é mais fácil fazer dessa forma?

Informar dois textos iguais não provê segurança alguma, você precisa executar exatamente a mesma coisa. Caso contrário, você poderá informar ao atacante que o usuário existe ou não, por outros caminhos.

Considere este código, INSEGURO:

```
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var hashedPassword string
    var username = r.PostFormValue("username")
    var password = r.PostFormValue("password")

    if username == "" || password == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Você precisa enviar os dados")
        return
    }

    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT `senha` FROM login WHERE usuario = ? LIMIT 1", username).Scan(&hashedPassword)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Senha ou usuário incorreto")
        return
    }

    if err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hashedPassword), []byte(password)); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Senha ou usuário incorreto")
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, "Conectado com sucesso")
}
```

O código acima sempre vai informar "Senha ou usuário incorreto" se você errar uma das coisas. Você pode dizer que o código acima cumpre o que o @Stormwind diz:

> Se você usa uma mensagem de erro genérica, você está "aumentando a segurança", uma vez que o atacante não saberá se pegou nomes válidos e existentes no seu sistema [...]

Mas.... Não. Isso não adiciona nenhuma segurança. Um atacante ainda consegue obter a informação original, observe que o tempo de processamento é diferente:

Usuário "QueNaoExiste":

```
curl -d "username=QueNaoExiste&password=a" http://127.0.0.1:8888/login -w " "%{time_total}
```

> Senha ou usuário incorreto 0,000

Usuário "QueExiste":

```
curl -d "username=QueExiste&password=a" http://127.0.0.1:8888/login -w " "%{time_total}
```

> Senha ou usuário incorreto 2,156

Usuário "QueExiste" e com a senha certa:

```
curl -d "username=QueExiste&password=umasenhamuitolouca" http://127.0.0.1:8888/login -w " "%{time_total}
```

> Conectado com sucesso 2,157

Um usuário inexistente não faz o BCrypt, portanto o resultado é mais rápido do aquele que faz a comparação. O `%{time_total}` informa o tempo total gasto até a requisição ser finalizada. Não basta apenas as mensagens serem iguais, você tem que impossibilitar a extração da informação verdadeira por outras vias. Neste caso especifico deve se proteger de *timming-attack*.

Isso é apenas UM dos milhares de métodos que podem ser utilizados, mesmo onde "a mensagem é igual". Em um outro caso real, existe um site *(não vou mencionar o nome aqui)* que ao fazer o login, o cliente recebe um `id`. Mas, quando tenta fazer login de uma conta inexistente o `id` é temporário. Basta que você espere algum tempo e experimente fazer um novo login. Se o novo `id` for diferente do antigo é porque não existe, se ele permanece igual.... Você acertou o usuário.

Uma mensagem igual, por mim, não garante nenhuma segurança. Existe mais coisas a serem feitas do que apenas "uma mensagem igual".

Comment: Normalmente sistemas mais modernos de validação de usuário se recomenda fazer uma espera forçada, justamente para evitar esse tipo de _side chanel attack_

Comment: Boa resposta. Ou seja, já que dar uma resposta genérica não necessariamente protege, é melhor dar uma resposta que realmente ajude o usuário legítimo. :)

Answer (score 16):

Já existem algumas *threads* no *Information Security*, site da *Stack Exchange* específico sobre segurança da informação, que trata, mais ou menos, do mesmo assunto. Na verdade lá existe uma *tag* específica sobre esse tópico, [user-enumeration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-enumeration).

Em uma das perguntas realizada lá, é questionado se existe alguma razão específica e se é útil mostrar uma mensagem de erro genérica como *"Senha ou nome de usuário estão errados"*. Falando com base na minha pesquisa relacionada a segurança, gostaria de maneira sintetizada compartilhar alguns pontos, que encontrei sobre o uso e funcionamento do sistema de login:

- Se você usa uma mensagem de erro genérica, você está "*aumentando a segurança*", uma vez que o atacante não saberá se pegou nomes válidos e existentes no seu sistema, entretanto você estará "*prejudicando*" o usuário que esquece suas credenciais de login frequentemente.

> [...] É benéfico aumentar a dificuldade para que os atacantes coletem nomes de usuários válidos, mas normalmente é um custo aos usuários. [...] Você terá que determinar se seus requisitos de segurança terão prioridade sobre a experiência do usuário.

Veja que uma mensagem de erro genérica não ajuda em nada ao usuário. Dar uma resposta genérica não necessariamente protege (veja as aspas e o itálico em "*aumentando a segurança*"), [então é melhor dar uma resposta que realmente ajude o usuário legítimo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245240/devo-mostrar-mensagens-de-erro-gen%C3%A9ricas-como-senha-ou-usu%C3%A1rio-errado-ou-mensa/245345#comment502853_245381).

> **A finalidade de uma mensagem de erro é ajudar o usuário que encontrou o erro**, a aprender como evitar o comportamento que causou o problema. O programa encontrou uma situação que não pode manipular e precisa dizer ao usuário, de modo que o usuário (ou outra pessoa) entenda e possa evitar a situação que o programa não pode manipular. [...] A mensagem de erro que diz: "ocorreu um erro inesperado" é totalmente inútil nesse objetivo. Dá ao usuário nenhuma sugestão sobre o que pode ser alterado para evitar o problema, ou até mesmo corrigir esse problema.

Em linhas gerais, não é sempre possível, determinar quem, o quê, onde, como, quando e por quê ocorreu o erro. Entretanto deve-se levar em conta, que uma boa mensagem de erro deverá conter uma "*espécie*" de exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável:

- Informar qual é o problema.
- Fazer você se sentir como se houvesse algo que você pudesse fazer sobre isso.
- Falar como um humano e ser uma extensão consistente da personalidade do resto da aplicação.

De maneira sintetizada, explique o mínimo para seu usuário, mas de maneira clara e compreensível, e se possível faça algo que permita ao usuário saber que o problema não está sendo ignorado. Deixe-os tomar alguma ação, como enviar os *logs* ou enviar um relatório de erro. Alternativamente, deixe-os saber que a ação automática já foi tomada e que seu pessoal técnico foi notificado automaticamente de que esse erro ocorreu e está trabalhando nisso.

Veja a imagem abaixo. Ela não é especificamente relacionado as senhas, mas demonstra bem o que quero dizer sobre as mensagens genéricas e UX:

[image: Windows Blue Death Screen]

Quem nunca ficou p*** quando viu essa tela da morte e queria quebrar o seu computador por que a Microsoft dava essa maldita mensagem de erro genérica azul? Esse é o sentimento que os usuários tem quando veem uma mensagem assim. Certo que são pouquíssimos os que conseguem resolver esse problema, mas veja como é ruim por si mesmo. Ainda como se não se basta-se, eles dão umas "*letrinhas em maiúscula*", dizem para eu procurar na internet uma solução para umas ""*letrinhas em maiúscula*"" que eu já esqueci quais são e ainda desligam o meu computador.

---

- O sistema de login em duas partes, em sites de grande porte, como o Google e a Microsoft, realmente vai contra a [sabedoria convencional da OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Error_Messages):

> Uma aplicação deve responder com uma mensagem de erro genérica, independentemente de o ID do usuário ou a senha estarem incorretas. Também não deve dar indicação para o status de uma conta existente.

Entretanto está é uma consideração entre segurança e usabilidade. Ainda é uma boa ideia para a maioria dos sites não divulgar se existe um nome de usuário, mas o risco precisa ser pesado contra o novo processo de registro de usuários.

- Outro ponto a se levar em conta é seu sistema de registro de usuário. Quando você tenta fazer o login, você mostra uma mensagem de erro genérica, mas na "*página ao lado*", você especifica todas as informações do seu sistema, nomes de usuários cadastrados válidos, sistema de senha, e-mails já registrados e outros afins. **A tentativa de se registrar com algum nome de usuário já não revela a mesma informação?**

Um simples ataque [*brute-force*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) na "*página ao lado*" já não danificaria todo seu sistema de login super seguro? Faltou equilibrar a segurança com usabilidade das páginas, portanto de nada adiantou dar uma resposta genérica ao usuário e você ainda foi invadido. Nesse último caso discutido recomendo a leitura dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32533/66203) e até pensar na [implementação de um *captcha*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59952/66203).

---

Por fim, em toda essa resposta novamente a palavra a se analisar é **usabilidade**. Assim como tudo relacionado à [UX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242887/66203), você terá que determinar se seus requisitos de segurança terão prioridade sobre a experiência do usuário.

> [...] A menos que você esteja pronto para sacrificar uma considerável quantidade significativa de usabilidade [...]

### Fontes

- [*Generic error message for wrong password or username - is this really helpful?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/62661)
- [*Is there any reason to not show users incorrectly entered passwords after a successful login?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/136379)
- [*New Gmail login system—going against conventional wisdom?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/88815)
- [*Is it unsafe to show message that username/account does not exist at login?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/158075)
- [*What is the recommended wording for a generic error message?*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/39101)
- [*Specific vs Generic error messages*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/60917)

Answer (score 12):

Hoje muito raramente alguém fará algo assim porque é mais fácil programar. Claro que se o programador for leigo, e muitos o são, talvez faça por desconhecimento, mas nunca é o caso de um grande site ou aplicativo.

Se você disser qual está certo, uma parte da autenticação está resolvida para o atacante e ele não precisa mais se preocupar, diminui a análise combinatorial que ele precisa fazer. Não sabendo se um deles está certo precisa continuar tentando outras opções na força bruta.

Há quem conteste isto porque com uma senha forte e **limitações de tentativas** a chance reduz bastante a tal ponto que este ganho, que nem é pequeno, se torna desnecessário. Assim pode dar uma informação mais útil para o usuário legítimo do que ele errou e precisa verificar. O que é um ganho na experiência do usuário, mas é pequeno.

O sistema de *login* "moderno" provavelmente mudou como melhoria de experiência. Como muitas pessoas gerenciam várias contas e senhas isto pode ajudar. Provavelmente eles preferiram facilitar para o usuário legítimo mesmo arriscando um pouco com o ilegítimo porque na prática o aumento do risco, apesar de grande, é estatístico.

Há uma corrente que considera que menos informação ajuda o usuário usar o sistema, mesmo que isto adicione passos. Tendo que escolher onde vai digitar pode confundir certos usuários. Um sistema guiado facilita. Isto provavelmente é verdade, mas prejudica usuários mais acostumados e que tem um passo separado a fazer. Nada que mude tanto assim, mas em UX pequenas coisas fazem diferença para o bem ou mal.

Mas é possível que também tenha mudado pela segurança. Ainda teria que acertar na força bruta o usuário e depois quando acertar teria que acertar a senha, pode até se tornar um novo tipo de barreira.

É possível que estejam usando até outras barreiras. E um sistema de autenticação diferente que até traga algumas vantagens contra ataque.

Nem falei que em telas muito pequenas cada vez mais comuns (relógios, por exemplo) onde a separação faz sentido.

Existem outros motivos para esta escolha, mas não costumam ser relevantes. O acesso ao banco de dados certamente não pesa na decisão. Isto deve ser otimizado. Mesmo que não seja, não deve pesar a mais.

Uma coisa importante a se analisar é o porte de quem usa a técnica. Assim como eu costumo dizer que muita gente vai atrás da mesma tecnologia da Google, Facebook, etc. quando eles não tem a mesma necessidade, estes fornecedores podem se valer disto, conforme o comentário do Bacco na pergunta. Para o volume deles não faz diferença.

O fato de existir autenticação em dois fatores não quer dizer nada porque muita gente não usa e ainda assim pede-se separado para estes usuários. Faz mais sentido a hipótese do Bacco.

Certamente estas empresas possuem estatísticas que mostram que é irrelevante ser esta proteção por obscuridade.

[Mais informações](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Por não ter conhecimento total do assunto que eu evitei elaborar uma resposta. Por exemplo, eu nunca mensurei o impacto de primeiro resgatar o usuário para depois resgatar a senha vs resgate simultâneo de usuário e senha; só sabia que tinha comunicação com o banco é que _talvez_ o latência pudesse ter alguma influência. Obrigado por sempre dar essas respostas multifacetadas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ainda preciso melhorar algumas porque essas coisas você vai lembrando de coisas novas, vai vendo o que os os outros lembraram e vai desenvolvendo, assim todo mundo aprende junto. Mas não poderia fazer nos próximos dias. A questão do banco tem maneiras de resolver para não ficar consultado toda vez, com algum risco, mas muito pequeno de criar uma condição de corrida, aí é questão de ver o que compensa. Mesmo que não otimize nada, o custo é muito pequeno para evitar o acesso piorando a experiência.

Answer (score 7):

Em relação as melhores práticas de `UX`, outras repostas já abordam suficientemente o assunto.

Em contraste com respostas que afirmam `segurança` como motivo:

**Não**, isso não protege os dados.

Como mencionado pelo @Inkeliz, em primeira instância o sistema deve verificar a natureza da requisição.

O servidor deve estar preparado para essa leitura, caso contrário, independente da UX implementada, o sistema estará vulnerável.

Há de se levar em consideração que um atacante disposto a invadir um sistema, não irá simplesmente realizar um ataque manual de tentativas para efetuar um login, ou tentar algum ataque de força bruta para descobrir 1 usuário e 1 senha que sejam válidos, pelo simples fato de ele poder "criar" seu próprio usuário e à partir desse "novo usuário" explorar falhas do "sistema".

Se não der para ele criar um "novo usuário", em caso de sistemas fechado, ou ele vai usar de `Engenharia Social`, ou ele vai atacar a rede para encontrar as falhas.

Falo superficialmente sobre este raciocínio nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216642/sistemas-devem-for%C3%A7ar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-a-criar-uma-senha-forte/216682#216682)

Quando o cerne da questão é "segurança" UX é irrelevante(a grosso modo, existem fatores em UX que podem de uma forma ou de outra colaborar para a falta de segurança). É necessário entender como são feito os ataques e para cada grupo de sistemas existem `N` tipos de ataques.

Diferente de sistemas fechados, na Web por exemplo, os servidores de cara já deixam uma porta aberta `full time` para receber requisições, então existem "farejadores(`sniffers`)" que encontram essas rotas colhendo informações que vão ser relevantes para dar um passo adiante a um ataque. Muitos servidores, são implementados com um nível de segurança mínimo e até sem, por despreparo de quem implementou. Então o servidor responde a requisições com `dados` que serão usados para a realização de um ataque. O sistema operacional, passa a ser o alvo(não o usuário "Maluco das pernas tortas" do face).

Existem grupos que estão fortemente equipados com as mais variadas tecnologias para realizar ataques, e o ataque bem realizado é imperceptível, o administrador nem vai ficar sabendo.

Em resumo a arquitetura da segurança deve levar em consideração a natureza do sistema, dos usuários e de possíveis ataques e usar isso a favor do sistema.

Em geral abaixo da superfície, **UX** é irrelevante para a segurança, como citado na resposta que coloquei link.

Answer (score 2):

**Sim**, isso é para ajudar a proteger os dados (e a conta).

Não porque necessariamente seja mais fácil, mas porque contribui um pouco mais na segurança. Não revelar qual dado está incorreto é uma forma de dificultar o acesso a um suposto invasor, e desta forma ele não sabe o quê errou (usuário ou senha).

Atualmente, sistemas mais seguros ainda pedem a senha quando o usuário, mesmo logado, tenta fazer operações críticas dentro da conta, coisas que podem afetar a própria conta e a segurança das informações, como excluir ou alterar dados pessoais, transações que envolvem valores e, principalmente, excluir a própria conta.